# is it possible to dare an incremental id to the html tags?

Tags: html, tags

I asked this question because I was writing code and I focused on this problem. Practically I created a table dynamically within a loop and I would like to give each column a name like "clm" + i.
where i is a variable that increases each time at the end of the cycle. Is it possible to do it?

per esempio

```
for(...)
 <table> 
<tr> <td id='clm'+i></td></tr>
</table>
i++;
```

Is the positioning of the quotation marks correct?

Comment: I'm wondering what you want to accomplish.However it is possible, as you can see in @Hoi_A his answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are pretty close to what I think you want to accomplish.

Basically, you want something along the lines of this:

```js
var myRow = document.getElementById("myRow");

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  myRow.innerHTML += '<td id="clm' + i + '">Cell</td>';
}

console.log(myRow.innerHTML); // You can also check the cells with inspect element
```

```html
<table>
  <tr id="myRow"></tr>
</table>
```

The example code here will find a row with the id `myRow` and simply append new `td` tags on the inside.

To note here is the `'<td id="clm' + i + '">Cell<td>'` part. As you can see I close the quotes and concatenate `i` in between to get the number into the id attribute.